# Using org-lookup-last to look up values in a table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have two tables. One table has a column (`$2`) of unsigned integers (`#+NAME: ATTRIBUTES`). One table is a lookup table (`#+NAME: ATTR-LOOKUP`) which takes each value from Column `$2` in `ATTRIBUTES`, and looks it up in Column `$1` in `ATTR-LOOKUP`, and places the corresponding value (a signed integer) back into the original table in column `$3`.

Sample table and formula I'm using:

```
#+NAME: ATTR-LOOKUP
|  1 | -5 |
|  3 | -4 |
|  5 | -3 |
...
```

Here is the main table:

```
#+NAME: ATTRIBUTES
| Attribute | Value | Mod    | Save | Skills          |    |
|-----------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+----|
| STR       |    13 | #ERROR |      | Athletics       | *  |
|-----------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+----|
| DEX       |    15 | #ERROR | *    | Acrobatics      | *  |
...
#+TBLFM: $3=(org-lookup-last $2 (remote(ATTR-LOOKUP, @1$1..@>$1)) (remote(ATTR-LOOKUP, @1$2..@>$2)) '>=)
```

Any ideas? I spent four hours last night googling and researching (not very well, clearly.)

So, to the question. With debugging enabled, it looks like the formula fails on the predicate. Can anyone see why it might fail, and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Changed the formula:

```
#+NAME: ATTR-LOOKUP
|  1 | -5 |
|  3 | -4 |
|  5 | -3 |

#+NAME: ATTRIBUTES
| Attribute | Value | Mod | Save | Skills     |   |
|-----------+-------+-----+------+------------+---|
| STR       |    13 |   5 |      | Athletics  | * |
|-----------+-------+-----+------+------------+---|
| DEX       |    15 |   5 | *    | Acrobatics | * |
| FEX       |    -4 |   3 | *    | Acrobatics | * |
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-lookup-last $2 '(remote(ATTR-LOOKUP, @1$2..@>$2)) '(remote(ATTR-LOOKUP, @1$1..@>$1)) '>=);L
```